# What information is shown on the Plist on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

What information is shown on the Plist on the iPhone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about the iPhone's root Info.plist file specifically?

Information on that can be found [here on the Apple developer site](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW1).

Comment: Thanks joost schuur for informative information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're asking what kind of data you should store in Plists. It's a file format suited for storing human-readable (strings, integers, etc) configuration data in a key-value or array manner, data that you'd read in your app and that you could also modify by opening the plist file in Xcode.

Comment: thnks luvieere ..i wanna to ask the same thing u said. can u highlighted the major issues which is necessary in plist.